# admin-ajax.php mixed content

Tags: ajax

### Cant access admin-ajax from https. In my js i wrote

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://'+window.location.host+'/admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type:'post',
    data:'action=bid_now_live_me&_pid='+ mypid ,
    success: function (data) {
```

### So I changed every url to https but still no luck. In chrome network I get

[image]

### In console just lot's of errors

[image]

Tried to force ssl by modifing my htaccess, wp-config and by using force ssl plugin. And of course I tried to disable all plugins.

Comment: Problem resolved by moving my site to different hosting, dont know why, but it works fine on digitalocean. Forgot to mention, this problem was only when I used https, the whole site worked fine exept this one admin-ajax, on http admin-ajax worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do something like this in your JS code:

```
url: 'https://'+window.location.host+'/admin/admin-ajax.php',
```

You should use [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and pass proper URL in there.

Let's say your AJAX call is located in file `my-js-file.js`. Somewhere in your theme/plugin you have something like this

```
wp_enqueue_script( '<SOME_HANDLE>', ... . 'my-js-file.js' , ...);
```

You should add this after it:

```
wp_localize_script( '<SOME_HANDLE>', 'MyScriptData', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

And in your JS file it should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: MyScriptData.ajax_url,
    type:'post',
```

Answer (score 0):

for a default Wordpress installation,

```
url: 'https://'+window.location.host+'/admin/admin-ajax.php',
```

should be

```
    url: 'https://'+window.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
```

i.e `/admin/` should be `/wp-admin/`.
I hope this helps.